# Sort a collection using linq or lambda expression and assign to collection

Tags: linq, lambda

I have to sort a collection based on sort-order field from another collection. I did it the following way.

```
var objresult = from err in ibusSoftErrors.iclbEmployerError
                            join codvalue in lclbCodeValue
                                on err.severity_id equals codvalue.icdoCodeValue.code_id
                            orderby codvalue.icdoCodeValue.code_value_order
                            select ibusSoftErrors.iclbEmployerError;
```

ibusSoftErrors.iclbEmployerError is the collection I would use in my grid. My problem is when I try to assign the query result to this collection am getting the following error.

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Help me out to get the collection sorted using lambda or linq.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `select err` instead of selecting the whole collection? :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `Collection<T>`?

Comment: @Destrictor, I tried using `select err`, still got the same error.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, for the complete project we are using collections. and this is a common method to prepare the collection and keep. This collection object would be used in different screens.

Answer (score 0):

Binding usually requires an IList implementation so

```
var objresult = from err in ibusSoftErrors.iclbEmployerError
                        join codvalue in lclbCodeValue
                            on err.severity_id equals codvalue.icdoCodeValue.code_id
                        orderby codvalue.icdoCodeValue.code_value_order
                        select err;
var toBind = objresult.ToList();
grid.ItemsSource = toBind;
```

should do it (assuming a WPF/Silverlight datagrid)

Comment: The grid source is not assigned in the same method. There is a framework for the UI, that will take care assigning the collection to the grid source. So I need the ibusSoftErrors.iclbEmployerError in proper sorted order.

Comment: @SelviMoies, does your framework convert the IEnumerable into an IList?

Comment: No vc. It will such find the collections under errors, and assign to the gird whose datasource is set to this collection. Can we not assign the sorted result back to collection. like instead of `var objresult` to `ibusSoftErrors.iclbEmployerError`?

Comment: What I mean is that your linq statement returns an IEnumerable which cannot be bound directly to a control. If you want to bind, convert it to an IList (by calling ToList, ToArray...)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @vc. I shall try it out.